# BigQuery: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a recurring query that *sometimes* works, and sometimes generates this error:

> Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Query:

```
create or replace table `dataset`.`table_name`

    partition by DATE(sales_effective_date)
  as (


SELECT * FROM `my-project`.`dataset`.`table_name`
WHERE DATE(sales_effective_date) > DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL -1825 DAY)
  );
```

Most recent job ID: `[redacted]-looker-poc:US.bquijob_2a22d114_164aa53e926`

A lot of people seem to post about this error but nobody seems to have answers, I'm guessing because BQ engineers reach out directly on their problem. So hi, reach out to me please! Thank you :)

Comment: Please submit a bug to [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) instead. If you aren't comfortable posting your project name in the bug, you can ask in the bug report to have someone contact you over email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
create or replace table `project.dataset.table_name`
partition by DATE(sales_effective_date) as 
SELECT * FROM `my-project.dataset.table_name`
WHERE DATE(sales_effective_date) > DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL -1825 DAY)
```

hope you see the difference from your version